# MySQL can't create/rename tables and/or variables

Tags: mysql

OK, this is really baffling me.

I'm using MySQL 5.5.20 on Mac OS X (Lion). Someone gave me an .MDB database to work on, so I brought it into MySQL. No problems initially.

Then I was cleaning up the database/tables/fields. I wanted all tables to have an ID field. In some cases, they existed but I wanted them to be called ID. In other cases, there was no such field, so I created one.

There is a table called CityList. I renamed it to Cities. I renamed the primary key field from CityList to ID.

There is another table called Venues. It has three fields VenuesID, VenueName, and CityList. I renamed the CityList field to CityID.

Then, I tried to rename VenuesID to ID. It failed with errorno: 150. I tried using Sequel Pro, I tried using command line. Nothing.

I tried renaming the Venues table to something else. Same result: 150.

I tried recreating the database after deleting it. Same result: 150.

I was able to import *exactly* the structure and data by calling the Venues table "Boxes." Not a whisper of a problem with that.

So, I thought I'd be clever. I exported the full structure and data into SQL statements, including the last table which CREATEd the Boxes table and INSERTed INTO Boxes. I edited the file to change all "Boxes" into "Venues" and recreated the database.

It worked, but.... I had mistyped "Venues" as "Venes". So the full database structure was there and all data. Just the table's name is wrong.

I can't rename it to Venues.

I've been destroying and retrying now for about an hour. It makes no sense. It feels like somewhere there is still some record in MySQL that the Venues table 1) still exists and 2) can't be altered.

*Any* suggestions?

P. S. My code to create is:

```
CREATE TABLE `Locations` (
  `VenuesID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CityID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VenueName` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VenuesID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**No, no Foreign Key constraints.**

Comment: Are there any foreign key constraints that reference the columns at issue?

Comment: @eggyal no foreign key constraints.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain?  You get an empty result from `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'`?

Comment: Can you pastebin the schema (`mysqldump --no-data yourdbname > voodoo.sql`)?

Comment: @eggyal color me red. yes, i do have a foreign constraint.... where'd that come from? and why doesn't it show in other places? Thank you, thank you, thank you! I found other references, deleted them, and voilà! Duh.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva: In what other places would you expect to see it?  It should appear in `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table on which it is defined; likewise in Sequel Pro under "relations" (or whatever the tab is called - I don't have it open in front of me).

Comment: @eggyal that's the thing. it *wasn't* in relations. hence my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

Some other table is constrained by a foreign key that references the column you are attempting to alter.

You can see all the foreign key constraints in your database by querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

The `TABLE_NAME` column in the output indicates the table on which the constraint has been defined.  You can also see the constraints in the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE [TABLE_NAME]`, or in Sequel Pro's "Relations" tab for that table (note that the Relations tab only shows foreign key constraints defined on the current table, *not* those which reference the current table: therefore you would otherwise have had to check the "Relations" tab for each table in your database to find any that reference the column in question...).